# Universal property of the cocomplete category of models of a limit sketch

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, universal-algebra, coalgebras, universal-property

Let $\mathscr{S}$ be a [limit sketch](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sketch) in a small category $\mathcal{E}$, i.e. just a collection of cones in $\mathcal{E}$. Then its category $\mathbf{Mod}(\mathscr{S})$ of models (i.e. functors $\mathcal{E} \to \mathbf{Set}$ which send the cones in $\mathscr{S}$ to limit cones) is cocomplete, in fact locally presentable. It enjoys the following universal property in the $2$-category of cocomplete categories:  If $\mathcal{C}$ is any cocomplete category, then
$$\mathrm{Hom}_c(\mathbf{Mod}(\mathscr{S}),\mathcal{C}) \simeq \mathbf{Mod}_{\mathcal{C}}(\mathscr{S}^{\mathrm{op}}).$$
Here, $\mathrm{Hom}_c$ denotes the category of cocontinuous functors, $\mathscr{S}^{\mathrm{op}}$ denotes the dual *colimit* sketch, and $\mathbf{Mod}_{\mathcal{C}}$ refers to $\mathcal{C}$-valued models.

A typical example of this universal property is $\mathrm{Hom}_c(\mathbf{Grp},\mathcal{C}) \simeq \mathbf{CoGrp}(\mathcal{C})$, that is, $\mathbf{Grp}$ is the universal example of a cocomplete category with an internal cogroup object.

The proof is a combination of two well-known results, so I assume that this universal property is also well-known. **Can someone confirm this and point me to literature which I can cite for this result?**

Maybe it follows from some of the theorems in [Kelly's book](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10abs.html) on enriched categories, chapter 6. But I am not sure.

---

Here is a sketch of the two-step proof I was thinking of. Let $G : \mathbf{Mod}(\mathscr{S}) \to [\mathcal{E},\mathbf{Set}] $ be the inclusion and $F : [\mathcal{E},\mathbf{Set}] \to \mathbf{Mod}(\mathscr{S})$ its left adjoint. Then by a "tensor-less" variant of Prop. 2.3.6. in [Tensor functors between categories of quasi-coherent sheaves](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.5147.pdf) (as you see, this is not quite the reference I need!) the category $\mathrm{Hom}_c(\mathbf{Mod}(\mathscr{S}),\mathcal{C})$ is equivalent to the category of those cocontinuous functors $Q^* : [\mathcal{E},\mathbf{Set}] \to \mathcal{C}$ such that $Q^* \to Q^* \circ G \circ F$ is an isomorphism; this is true iff the right adjoint $Q_* : \mathcal{C} \to [\mathcal{E},\mathbf{Set}]$ factors over $\mathbf{Mod}(\mathscr{S})$. By the well-known universal property of $[\mathcal{E},\mathbf{Set}]$ as the free cocompletion of $\mathcal{E}^{\mathrm{op}}$ (for instance, Section 4.4 in Kelly's book), $Q^*$ corresponds to a functor $P : \mathcal{E}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathcal{C}$ via $Q^* = P \otimes_{\mathcal{E}} -$, and hence $Q_* = \mathrm{Hom}(P(-),-)$. By the Yoneda Lemma, the requirement that $Q_*$ factors over $\mathbf{Mod}(\mathscr{S})$ exactly means that $P$ is a model of $ \mathscr{S}^{\mathrm{op}}$.

---

I have found a reference: Theorem 2.2.4 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3104) (actually, I knew this paper, but I somehow forgot that the theorem is in there). But the authors also explicitly state that this theorem is well-known. I would be happy with a more "classical" or "original" reference.

Comment: The group of Christian Lair and Rene Guitard in Paris 7 Diderot had a sophisticated calculus of sketches that they published in their own private journal called [*Diagrammes*](http://www.numdam.org/journals/DIA/) in the 1980s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the earliest reference is Theorem 2.5 in

> A. Pultr, **The right adjoints into the categories of relational systems**, Reports of the Midwest Category
> Seminar IV. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 1970

Pultr's "relational theories" are exactly small realized limit sketches.

Remark: I have recently generalized the result to large limit sketches ([arXiv:2106.11115](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.11115)).

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately in the form you write, I do not have a one-line-reference, someone might be able to find it. I will provide enough literature and statements in the case in which $\mathscr{S}$ **is a small category with finite limits** and $\mathbf{Mod}_C(\mathscr{S})$ is defined to be $\mathbf{Lex}(\mathscr{S}, C)$. In the case of a category with finite colimits, the notion of model will be dual and I will choose $\mathbf{Rex}(\mathscr{S}, C)$. This argument **can be adapted to the sketch case**, but the notation and a couple of details would not look as nice, I will indicate enough literature to accomplish the adaptation **at the end of my answer**.

> **Prop. 1** There exists an equivalence of categories, $$ \text{lan}_i(-): \mathbf{Rex}(\mathscr{S}^\circ, C) \leftrightarrows \mathbf{coCont}(\mathbf{Lex}(\mathscr{S}, \text{Set}), C) : i^*.$$

*Proof*: Let me call $i: \mathscr{S}^\circ \to \mathbf{Mod}(\mathscr{S})$ the *Yoneda* embedding. This map induces in a natural way a map $i^*: \mathbf{coCont}(\mathbf{Lex}(\mathscr{S}, \text{Set}), C) \to \mathbf{Rex}(\mathscr{S}^\circ, C). $ In the opposite direction we define $\text{lan}_i(-) : \mathbf{Rex}(\mathscr{S}^\circ, C) \to \mathbf{coCont}(\mathbf{Lex}(\mathscr{S}, \text{Set}), C).$ Thus we need to show that,

1. $i^* \circ \text{lan}_i \cong \mathbb{1}.$
2. $  \text{lan}_i \circ i^* \cong \mathbb{1}.$

1) follows from **Prop. 3.7.3** in  *Borceux*, **Handbook of Categorical Algebra**, vol. I.

2) follows from **Thm. 1.46(v)** in *Adamek and Rosický*, **Locally presentable and accessible categories**.

If one reads carefully, the whole **Prop. 1** follows from **LPAC**[1.46(v)], my intention was to set enough context to make it more readable.

---

**On the sketch-version.**

The sketch version of the statement follows from **Prop. 1** via **Lemma 4.2.2** in *Borceux*, **Handbook of Categorical Algebra**, vol. III. The lemma shows how to replace a (limit) sketch with a finitely complete category without changing its models.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that you have a proof by combining two known results, just like me. I was hoping for a reference for the precise statement. Meanwhile I have also found Theorem 6.23 in Kelly's "Basic concepts ...", which is very similar, but not quite the same. (Notice that the $\mathcal{F}$ there is supposed to be a small set, so that it does not include the case of all cocontinuous functors.)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, someone else could do much better than what I have done here. Could you at least mention the two results that you use? I am curious. Also, a direct proof could just work fine.

Comment: I have added the proof in my question above.

Comment: Thanks, Martin!

Comment: I have found a non-classical reference, see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

The case of a Lawvere theory is covered (**Theorem 13**) in the paper **[Internal Coalgebras in Cocomplete Categories: Generalizing the Eilenberg-Watts-Theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.08113)**, by *Porst* and *Laurent Poinsot*. The paper is on arXiv since today.